# How to define a list or a map (complex objects) as Variables in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, yaml

I want my variable to be an object or a list, but it results in errors:

```
dev-trigger-deployment:
    variables:
        JOB_RUN_PARAMETERS_LIST:
            sourceProjectId: my_project_id
```

runs into `jobs:dev-trigger-deployment:variables:job_run_parameters_list config uses invalid data keys: sourceprojectid`

```
dev-trigger-deployment:
    variables:
        JOB_RUN_PARAMETERS_LIST:
            - "sourceProjectId=my_project_id"
```

runs into `variable definition must be either a string or a hash`

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#store-multiple-values-in-one-variable):

> You cannot create a CI/CD variable that is an array of values, but you
> can use shell scripting techniques for similar behavior. 
>  
> For example, you can store multiple values separated by a space in a
> variable, then loop through the values with a script:
>
> ```
> job1:
>   variables:
>     FOLDERS: src test docs
>   script:
>     - |
>       for FOLDER in $FOLDERS
>         do
>           echo "The path is root/${FOLDER}"
>         done
> ```

So it is not possible to have variable value as object or list, only as a string which can be parsed further in `script` section.